# Accessing properties/fields within functions and event handlers in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is declared as a property so that I can access it within other functions and event handlers but seeing as I'm new to c# I can't figure out how to do this properly

Declaring the dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, int> occurrenceDictionary { get; set; }
```

I have two functions. The first `functionOne` turns a list of words into a `dictionary<string, int>` where `string` is a word, and `int` is the number of times that word occurs in the list.

```
public string functionOne(List<string> myList)
{     
    foreach (string item in myList)
    {
        if (!occurrenceDictionary.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            occurrenceDictionary.Add(item, 1);
            }
        else
        {
            occurrenceDictionary[item]++;
        }
    }
    return maxKey;
}
```

The second function compares user input `wordSearch.Text` to this dictionary `occurenceDictionary` and if they match, then the user will be told how many times this word occurs (the keys are the words, the values are the amount of occurrences).

```
public int word_search(Dictionary<string, int> myDict)
{
    if(myDict != null)
    {
        if (myDict.ContainsKey(wordSearch.Text))
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }  
}
```

Now I have an event listener that is waiting for the user to click the `Search` button. This is the part I'm having the most trouble with, I don't know how to call my `word_search` function properly inside the event handler, because the way I have it at the moment, I always get a `NullReferenceException` and it says to fix it I have to add

`if(occurencesDictionary != null) ...` But adding this to functionOne doesn't make sense to me because I want the items to be added to the dictionary regardless of whether its empty or not because `functionOne` is populating the dictionary. So I'm not sure how else to get around this problem

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or perhaps show me an easier method that would be helpful

Comment: Did you call `occurrenceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>` anywhere before using it?

Comment: no, turns out that was my problem. like i said, new to c#

Answer (score 0):

> ... But adding this to functionOne doesn't make sense to me because I want the items to be added to the dictionary regardless of whether its empty or not because functionOne is populating the dictionary.

`occurencesDictionary` is not empty, It's not even initialized.

You will have do first initialize it before using it.
Either you do it in the constructor or by property initializer:

```
Dictionary<string, int> occurrenceDictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You only declared but never initialized (with new) your hash variable so it is always null.

Answer (score 0):

You need public Dictionary occurrenceDictionary = new Dictionary();

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Dictionary<string, int> occurrenceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        public string functionOne(List<string> myList)
        {
            string maxKey = "";

            foreach (string item in myList)
            {
                if (!occurrenceDictionary.ContainsKey(item))
                {
                    occurrenceDictionary.Add(item, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    occurrenceDictionary[item]++;
                }
            }
            return maxKey;
        }
        public int word_search(Dictionary<string, int> myDict)
        {
            if(myDict != null)
            {
                if (myDict.ContainsKey(wordSearch.Text))
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return 1;
         }

        private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            occurrenceDictionary.Add("hello", 1);
        }
    }
}
```